# Is This Function Tail-Recursive? Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, tail-recursion

Is the following function tail-recursive? If not, what might I do to modify it?

```
(define (euclids-alg n1 n2)
 (cond((= n1 0) n2)
      ((= n2 0) n1)
      ((= n1 n2) n1)
      ((> n1 n2) (euclids-alg (- n1 n2) n2))
      ((< n1 n2) (euclids-alg n1 (- n2 n1)))))
```

Comment: The function is euclid's algorith to find greatest common denominators if anyone was wondering.

Comment: It appears that you're working under the assumption that `n1` and `n2` are numbers.  If that's the case, then there's no reason to check `(< n1 n2)` in the final clause.  Since you know that `(= n1 n2)` and `(> n1 n2)` are false, it _must_ then be the case that `(< n1 n2)`, so the last check is redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your function is [tail recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), because the recursive call is in *tail position* - meaning, it's the last thing it's done after the recursion returns. Take a look at the [specification](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.20) to better understand when we have a valid tail call and when we don't.